# Is there a better way to fill this autocomplete? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, autocomplete

I have a textbox that autocompletes from values in a SQL Server database. I also created a stored procedure, which is very simple:

[Stored procedure code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rj11.jpg)

My code is this:

```
public AutoCompleteStringCollection AutoCompleteFlight(TextBox flight)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionLoader.ConnectionString("Threshold")))
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection flightCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand flights = new SqlCommand("AutoComplete_Flight", connection);
        flights.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

        SqlDataReader readFlights = flights.ExecuteReader();

        while (readFlights.Read())
        {
            flightCollection.Add(readFlights["Flight_Number"].ToString());
        }

        return flight.AutoCompleteCustomSource = flightCollection;
    }
}
```

Is there a point to having this stored procedure since it's such a simple query? Or am I doing this wrong, since it still has to use the data reader and insert it into the collections.

My previous code before the stored procedure was:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionLoader.ConnectionString("Threshold")))
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection flightCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand flights = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Flight_Number FROM Ramp_Board", connection);

    SqlDataReader readFlights = flights.ExecuteReader();

    while (readFlights.Read())
    {
        flightCollection.Add(readFlights["Flight_Number"].ToString());
    }

    return flight.AutoCompleteCustomSource = flightCollection;
}
```

Is the second piece of code better or are they both wrong, and there is a way better way of doing this?

Comment: If you have a DBA on the project, or just someone who is an expert in SQL, then stored procedures are possibly better (as they can be 'tweaked' without having to redeploy the code.   In modern .NET, entity framework is a better thing, because all of that repeated code (opening a connection, running SP or SQL, reading data, closing connection etc) is handled in 1 line.

Comment: how many records does it bring back

Comment: @duerzd696 right now there will be around 200 records. But everyday it will grow by around 10-15 records

Answer (score 0):

"Better way" is a little undefined.

If you are looking for a performance answer of stored procedure or not, I'm not sure it matters all that much with that small of a data set and a simple query.  Stored procedures shine when there are complex operations to perform that can limit back and forth with the server or limit the amount of data returned. In your case, the server side effort is the same either way, and the amount of data returned is also the same. @Niel points out that the procedures can be updated server side without changing your deployed code. This is another useful feature of Stored procedures that you probably will not need for this scenario though.

If you are looking for an alternate code answer then you could use a DataAdapter instead of a DataReader. There are many articles on this site that talk about the performance of the two, and most of them agree that they are more or less the same. The only exception is if you dont't plan on reading all of the rows. In your case, you are reading the whole table, so they are effectively the same.

```cs
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable", connection);

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDA= new SqlDataAdapter();
    sqlDA.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    // Fill table from SQL using the command and connection
    sqlDA.Fill(table);
    
    // Fill autoComplete from table
    autoComplete.AddRange(table.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr["ColumnName"].ToString()).ToArray());
```

If you decide to use this kind of a LINQ statement, it is best to set the column to not allow nulls, or add a where that filters nulls. I'm not sure how or if AutoCompleteStringCollection handles nulls.